# Sort a chart from first value till last row and column

Tags: excel, vba

I recoded a macro and then have been trying to edit the code so that it will sort the chart no matter how many values it has. I am getting an error about range of object global failed. [image]

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row

LastCol = Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Q7", LastRow), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort
        .SetRange Range("Q7", LastCol)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: `Range("Q7", LastCol - 1)` this will not make a valid range - maybe you can show us how `LastRow` is declared and how you populate it.  FYI without column/row headers in the screenshot it's difficult to know where on the sheet your data is located...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Q7", Cells(LastRow, "Q")), _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Sort
       .SetRange Range("Q7", Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
       .Header = xlNo
       .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
   End With
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).